# UIButton UIPopUpController programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipopovercontroller, uibarbuttonitem

having difficulty getting `UIButton` Items to show.. I want to place several `UIButtons` within my `UIPopUpController`.  I'm doing everything in a storyboard and I need to do this section programmatically.

```
- (void)showPopover:(id)sender
{
    if(![popoverController isPopoverVisible])
    {
        myPopOver = [[PopUp alloc] init];
        popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myPopOver] ;
        [popoverController  setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 200.0f)];
        permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        CGRect rect = (CGRect)[sender frame];
        rect.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - rect.size.height;           
        [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    }
    else
    {
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in this example relating to `UIBarButtonItem`... What problem are you having?

Comment: Oh ok. The fact that OP is not using `-presentFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:` threw me. It's the obvious choice.

Comment: sorry it should say UIButton (not UIBarButton), I'm sorry for letting the revision take so long.. I posted and this is the first I've checked back.  I'm trying to place several UIButtons within an empty UIPopUpController.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a UINavigationController (it has already a navigation bar where you can attach buttons items) and add it as the content of your UIPopoverController. The UINavigationController can be istantiated using the initWithRootViewController method. In this case the controller would be your Popup class. For example, inside your showPopover method, you could do the following:

```
PopUp* myPopOver = [[PopUp alloc] init];
UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myPopOver];
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
// do other stuff here to present you UIPopoverController
[myPopOver release];
[navController release];
```

Now, inside your PopUp class, within viewDidLoad method, you can customize the UINavigationController navigationBar. For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UIBarButtonItem *aButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Show" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(somethingSelector:)];          
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = aButtonItem;
  [aButtonItem release];
}
```

where somethingSelector is like the following:

```
- (void)somethingSelector:(id)sender
{
   // your custom actions
}
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively you can avoid to use the UINavigationController and create UIToolbar inside your PopUp class. Inside the UIToolbar you can attach UIBarButtonItems. See [UIToolbar Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: what if it was the issue of using a UIButton as I posted (fixed post).  Do I need to add CGRect and place the UIButtons in coodinates?